# Is before_action/filter in application_controller.rb a bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

Consider the following

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :maintenance_mode

private

def maintenance_mode
      @settings = Setting.first
      if @settings.maintenance
        if logged_in?
          if !current_user.admin?
            redirect_to maintenance_url
          end
        else
          redirect_to maintenance_url
        end
      end

end
```

is there a performance issue or bad practice in general to use before_actions globally? So i created a maintenance mode, where if in the database there is a true value on the maintenance attribute(which will be checked on each request i assume), and its likely not the best way, so is there a workaround in that?

I can imagine of a cron job/rake task checking every minute in a background process but what i really want to know is before_action a bad thing in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip unnecessary logic and queries by using your session and cache

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :maintenance_mode

  private
  def maintenance_mode
    unless session[:maintainence_mode].present?
      @settings = Rails.cache.fetch { Setting.first }
      session[:maintainence_mode] = @settings.maintenance
    end

    if session[:maintainence_mode]
      if logged_in?
        if !current_user.admin?
          redirect_to maintenance_url
        end
      else
        redirect_to maintenance_url
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This way you can call `before_filter` than will most of the times check if the value in `session[:maintanence_mode]` is set or not instead of performing the query each time.

You should also use `Rails.cache` or `cookies`

Using rails cache to fetch or get the `Setting` model

```
@settings = Rails.cache.fetch { Setting.first }
```

or

using `cookies` to store value instead of `session` which gives you support for expiry

```
cookies[:_mmode] = { :value => @settings.maintanence,\
  :expires => 1.hour.from_now }
```

Comment: I might be missing something - but if I visit your site while it is in maintenance mode now my session always thinks the site is in maintenance mode which does not seem right; I will need to wait for the session to timeout before using the site again. Terrible user experience trade off for better performance (which might not be needed).

Comment: I agree with you that storing it in the session is a mistake if it is the case you are telling. But there are alternatives like cookies and cache which can expire. I prefer cache if it is for all users.

Comment: @MohamedOsama how do you work with this line `@settings = Rails.cache.fetch { Setting.first }` as it says `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)`

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider a before_action any worse than anything else. You'll probably need to implement `skip_before_action` in your other controllers on certain routes, and some refactoring with controller helpers might make it possible to avoid extra database lookups. On the whole before actions are a major utility of rails and not something worth avoiding for performance reasons.